# Can SharePoint be used to maintain employee forms?

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, web-parts

We'd like to create something within SharePoint that would allow to ensure a set of forms is completed for each employee (i.e., Tax forms, non-compete, etc.).  HR staff would have access to a page listing employees and upon selecting a specific employee, they would be shown a list of these completed forms which could be opened to view the document.

Is this scenario something that can be done fairly easy with out of the box features?  Or would a custom workflow, web part, or something else be the best bet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do it out of the box would be to use a single Document Library (or possibly Forms Library) that has multiple document/form templates in it. Then create a View that groups by Created By. HR could then expand on an Employee and see what has been filled out.

To limit an Employee from seeing the forms of another Employee, set the View and Edit options to [Only Their Own](http://sharepoint2007.microsoft.com/Blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=58). Make sure that HR has a higher level of permissions for the list and/or site in order to see all Employees.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have complex workflows - my advice will be to populate SharePoint List using InfoPath Forms ([this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/infopath/archive/2007/03/26/submitting-to-a-sharepoint-list.aspx) will be a good start).

In other case solution heavily depends on your business requirements and may vary from simple SP List to custom workflows with infopath forms and custom webparts.